# Convert a char* to a wchar_t*

Tags: python, c++, cython

I'am using the following function (I can't change the signature)

```py
cdef extern from "external.h":
    int EP_ProtectedStringByID(int ID, char * Buffer, int Len)
```

This function gives me a Widestring but formatted as a sequence of char caracter.

```py
buf_size = EP_ProtectedStringByID(2, b'', 0)
buf_string_2 = <char *> malloc((buf_size + 1) * sizeof(char))
if EP_ProtectedStringByID(2, buf_string_2, buf_size) != 0:
    for i in range(buf_size):
        print(buf_string_2[i], end=" - ")
```

The type of *buf_string_2* is **bytes**

The content of buf_string_2 is : (as you can see it's widestring)

> 67 - 0 - 39 - 0 - 101 - 0 - 115 - 0 - 116 - 0 - 32 - 0 - 117 - 0 - 110 - 0 - 32 - 0 - 116 - 0 - 101 - 0 - 120 - 0 - 116 - 0 - 101 - 0 - 32 - 0 - 97 - 0 - 118 - 0 - 101 - 0 - 99 - 0 - 32 - 0 - 100 - 0 - 101 - 0 - 115 - 0 - 32 - 0 - 99 - 0 - 97 - 0 - 114 - 0 - 97 - 0 - 99 - 0 - 116 - 0 - -24 - 0 - 114 - 0 - 101 - 0 - 115 - 0 - 32 - 0 - 61 - -40 - -121 - -36 - 60 - -40 - -5 - -33 - 13 - 32 - 66 - 38 - 15 - -2 - 32 - 0 - -23 - 0 - 116 - 0 - 114 - 0 - -30 - 0 - 110 - 0 - 103 - 0 - 101 - 0 - 115 - 0 - 32 - 0 - 33 - 0 - 33 - 0 - 33 - 0 -

and the corresponding sequence must be

> "C'est un texte avec des caractères ‍♂️ étrânges !!!"

I would like to retrieve this widestring and show-it in python

Actually I'm doing this without success cause conversion stop after the "second char" which is **\0**

```py
    cdef extern from "cstdlib":
        size_t mbstowcs(wchar_t * dest, const char * src, size_t max)

    if EP_ProtectedStringByID(2, buf_string_2, buf_size) != 0:
        buf_string = <wchar_t *> malloc((buf_size // sizeof(wchar_t) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t))
        mbstowcs(buf_string,buf_string_2,buf_size)
        pystr_2 = PyUnicode_FromWideChar(buf_string, -1)
        wide_string = str(<object> pystr_2)
        print('WideString :', wide_string)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What did I miss? What does this have to do with Python?

Comment: You say that your EP_ProtectedStringByID already gives out wide string. For whatever reason (perhaps only known to you) it puts that to char*. Why you pass that to mbstows ... and what you expect ... it is clearly not zero terminated char string that mbstows expects?

Comment: @DarkKnight : It's a Cython code, the goal is to call a C function from Python

Comment: @ÖöTiib : Depends on the context, sometimes **EP_ProtectedStringByID()** gives me ansistring (so no problem), sometimes it's raw binary data (a file). And it could be a widestring. But the signature just allow me to have char*.

My goal is to convert this succession of char* and convert-it to widestring.

Comment: @MelectronVolt so it can be pointer to whatever depending on (undisclosed) context. Therefore perhaps you have to pass it to one of family of filter functions that each can turn one of possible alternatives to wide string depending on that context and not to mbstows that expects very narrow kind of input.

Comment: Do you think casting this pointer to a **void* pointer** and after that casting it to a wchar_t* is possible ?

Comment: Isn't this what the `size` parameter `PyUnicode_FromWideChar` is for? Alternatively go via `bytes` then `decode`?

Comment: Casting any data pointer to char* or void* is possible and then casting that to wchar_t* is also possible but unless original data pointer was wchar_t* usage of it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @ÖöTiib It was wchar_t* usage but cython doesn't want to let me assign void * to wchar_t*...
cdef void* p_caster

p_caster = buf_string_2
buf_string = p_caster


cython_protect.pyx:156:21: Cannot assign type 'void *' to 'wchar_t *'

Comment: If I change the signature to int EP_ProtectedStringByID(int ID, wchar_t * Buffer, int Len)
It works but I can't extract binary data and ansistring... :/

Comment: Find a way, I will answer my question properly after some testing. Thanks all.

Comment: Concerning the title of your question, you don't have any arrays of pointers there.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks it's corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To sum up, I use an external library which has this signature :

```py
cdef extern from "external.h":
    int External_Function(int ID, char * Buffer, int Len)
```

- This function can fill the buffer with **wchar_t** or **char** depending on context.
- If the function, fills the memory with **wchar_t** the tip is to convert the pointer **char*** to **wchar_t***

```py
cdef char * buf_string_2
cdef wchar_t * buf_string
cdef PyObject * pystr_2

buf_string_2 = <char *> malloc((buf_size + 2) * sizeof(char))

if External_Function(2, buf_string_2, buf_size) != 0:
    buf_string_2[buf_size] = b'\0'
    buf_string_2[buf_size+1] = b'\0'
    p_caster = buf_string_2
    buf_string = <wchar_t*><void*>buf_string_2
    pystr_2 = PyUnicode_FromWideChar(buf_string, -1)
    wide_string = str(<object> pystr_2)
    print('WideString :', wide_string)
else:
    print("Error can't extract string 2")
```

Thanks all,